# Problem with initializing existing canvas with PixiJs

Tags: reactjs, pixi.js

As titled,

Is it possible to initialize canvas with image on it using Pixi so that i can add filter on top of it? Im using gsap 3.2.6 and Pixi 5.2.4.

I have the canvas created like this (using React btw)

```
useEffect(() => {

        let ctx = imgDisplayer.current.getContext('2d');
        let img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            imgDisplayer.current.width = img.width; // To set canvas width to image width
            imgDisplayer.current.height = img.height; // To set canvas height to image height
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            setCanvas(imgDisplayer.current);
        }
        img.src = source;
    }, []);
```

That setCanvas is to store the loaded canvas into state, so that i can use it to initialize Pixi.

```
if (canvas){
    const app = new Pixi.Application({
        width: 1300,
        height: 866,
        backgroundColor: 0x000000, 
        autoResize: true, 
        view: canvas
    });
}
```

Problem is, this throws me the following error

```
Error: This browser does not support WebGL. Try using the canvas renderer
```

If only i could fetch an https image (direct image link) then this wouldn't be a problem, and i can load the image using Pixi.Sprite insteaad.. but because of cross origin, i cannot think of way on how to render the image. I can render it just fine on canvas, but not with Pixi.

Answer (score 0):

The error you pasted is saying that your browser does not support WebGL.

1. Please check WebGL support on those pages: https://get.webgl.org/ , https://webglreport.com/
2. Can you try to initialize Pixi on some simpler page just to check if it works for you? I mean, just create simple html page (without React etc), try to setup Pixi there and try to draw anything (some red circle etc).

Comment: If just simple Pixi, then it would work. The post i created above was the workaround i thought of to get Pixi to load https image. I already posted it in their Github about the above and they said my approach was totally wrong. In any case, the real problem that i encountered was to load https images with Pixi, but it throws me CORS error. I can just show the image fine on canvas using drawImage, but not with Pixi.

Comment: can paste that error about "cross origin" from chrome or firefox console?